# Problem with RPM to DEB conversion by using alien

Tags: deb, rpm

I am facing problem with installing my laptop drivers which are in rpm package. I have tried to install them bu using 'alien', but unfortunately that did not work. It is generating warning when I convert the package.rpm into package.deb:

```
rashid@rashid-laptop:~/Desktop$ sudo alien --script -k ras.rpm  
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54<br> 
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54<br> 
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 307e3d54 <br>
Unpacking of 'ras.rpm' failed at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package/Rpm.pm line 153.
```

Comment: what is `ras.rpm` ?  Where have you been looking for drivers that either are available in deb format or as source code?

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and grabbed ras-something-src.rpm from [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/11655788/dir/opensuse/com/ras-176-1.2.noarch.rpm.html).

It appears to just be a python script and a readme.

If you use alien -g it will just generate the build directory so you can examine the contents.  Here they are on pastebin [ras.py](http://pastebin.com/gF4yP5Jm) and [README](http://pastebin.com/CzcCpQaS).

Even with the key warning the rpm to deb conversion succeeds.  I would look at the [debian packaging guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) and just use `sudo alien -g whatever.rpm` to generate your build directory.  Then go through the normal package build steps.